# Proving convergence of $\int_0^1 |\frac{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}{\ln{x}}|dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove convergence of the following integral: $$\int_0^1 \left|\frac{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}{\ln{x}}\right|dx.$$
First, I made a substitution $x=1/t$. Thus, I got the following integral: $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}}-\sqrt{t}}{\ln{\frac{1}{t}}}\right|\frac{1}{t^2}dt.$$
The integrand function is bounded near $1$, and also approaches $0$ as $t\to\infty$, but I'm not sure how to properly prove that it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll follow your idea to substitute $x=1/t$. That transforms the integral to
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{t-1}{t^{5/2}\ln t}\,dt $$
Since $\lim_{t\to 1^+}\frac{t-1}{\ln t}=1$, the singularity at $t=1$ is removable, so we only have to worry about the convergence of
$$\int_3^\infty\frac{t-1}{t^{5/2}\ln t}\,dt $$
For $t\ge 3$, we have
$$0<\frac{t-1}{t^{5/2}\ln t}<\frac{t}{t^{5/2}\ln t}<\frac{t}{t^{5/2}}=\frac{1}{t^{3/2}} $$
Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!